# Confusion in understanding meaning of $E(X\mid Y)$ and $E(E(x\mid y))=E(x)$

Tags: probability

> Confused in understanding meaning of $E(X\mid Y)$ and $E(E(X\mid Y))=E(X)$

I know $E(X\mid Y=y_i)$ is average value of random variable $X$ at $Y=y_i$. 
Now i did not understanding following -

1. what is $E(X\mid Y)$?
2. How $E(X\mid Y)$ is function of Y? $E(X\mid Y=y_i) $ is function of $X$ right?(pls correct me if i am wrong)
3. How is $E(X)=E(E(X\mid Y))$

$E(X) = \sum_y E(X\mid Y=y_i ) P(Y=y_i) = \sum_y \sum_x xP(X=x\mid Y=y_i)P(Y=y_i)$

I have recently started probability and statistics. Pls elaborate in detail (assume me a layman). I also refered to in wiki. I did not understand here.

Comment: $X| Y= y$ is a random variable with $P(x= X | Y = y) =\frac{P(x=X,y=Y)}{ P(y=Y)}$ and $E_{X| Y= y}(X) = \sum_x x P(x= X | Y = y) =  \sum_x x \frac{P(x=X,y=Y)}{P(y=Y)}=f(y)$ and $E_Y(f(Y)) = \sum_y f(y) P(Y=y) =  \sum_y P(Y=y) \sum_x x\frac{P(x=X,y=Y)}{P(y=Y)}$ $= \sum_x x  \sum_y P(x=X,y=Y) = \sum_x x P(x=X) = E_X(X)$

Comment: @reuns sir in line 2 - last, how can we say it as function of y. probability is a number between 0 and 1. and summation over x. I am not able to infer from here. Rest all i understood.

Comment: Also $E(X/Y)$ is same as $E(X/Y=y_i)$ ? If so say, Y= 1,2,3 then here what is $E(X/Y)$? is it $E(X/Y=1) $ or $E(X/Y=2) $  or $E(X/Y=3) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an example ought to clear your doubts up. Suppose we throw a dice. Whatever number shows up on the dice, we toss a coin that many times. We want to study the number of heads obtained.

Now let $X$ denote the number of heads obtained and $Y$ denote the number on the dice. 
As you can see, the value that $X$ takes depends on $Y$.

Also note that $X|Y$ is a random variable. 
In general, the mass function of the conditional distribution in the discrete case is given by:

$$P(X=x|Y =y) = \frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} \quad(1)$$

And for a continuous random variable, the density function of the conditional distribution is given by:

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y{y}} \quad (2)$$

where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint probability density function and $f_Y(y)$ is the marginal density function of $y$.

1. What is the expected number of heads if it is given that a $3$ showed up on the dice?

Here we are looking at $E(X|Y = 3)$.

2. This question is answered above.
3. Lets prove this for the continuous case:

$$E(X|Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$$

$$E(E(X|Y = y)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx dy$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|Y}(x|y) f_Y(y) dx dy$$

$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx dy \quad \text{Using (2)}$$

$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy dx$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X}(x) dx$$
$$=E(X)$$

Comment: sir, thank you. Pls clarify my doubt above(below reruns sir comment)

Comment: The $y$ needs to be specified in $E(X|Y =y)$.

Comment: Tq. But any idea why E(X/Y) was introduced - it is confusing right? in fact we can not calculate if specific Y=y not given.

Comment: Also sir how can we say E(X/Y=y) a function of y. I could understand from your exampple(Number of heads depend on number on dice). But from formula how can we infer(pls see rerun 2nd line - last part )

Comment: Generally, $E(X|Y)$ means $E(X|Y=y)$ for some variable $y$ in the space of values that $Y$ can take.